# Ninja Build throw error

Tags: g++, ninja

I am trying to do ninja build as below

```
gn gen PathToBinary --args='is_debug=false symbol_level=0  proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" use_cfi_diag=true enable_nacl=false treat_warnings_as_errors = true'

 ninja -C PathToBinary path
```

It throw error as

```
[1/10551] ACTION //cc/proto:proto_internal_gen(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
FAILED: pyproto/cc/proto/memory_allocation_pb2.py gen/cc/proto/memory_allocation.pb.cc gen/cc/proto/memory_allocation.pb.h 
python ../../tools/protoc_wrapper/protoc_wrapper.py --include cc/proto/cc_proto_export.h --protobuf gen/cc/proto/memory_allocation.pb.h --proto-in-dir ../../cc/proto --proto-in-file memory_allocation.proto --use-system-protobuf=0 -- ./protoc --cpp_out dllexport_decl=CC_PROTO_EXPORT:gen/cc/proto --python_out pyproto/cc/proto
./protoc: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./protoc)
./protoc: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./protoc)
```

please help to fix thanks.

**OS Details**

No LSB modules are available.

**Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty**

Comment: Old OS, no object `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` (or `GLIBCXX_3.4.20`) in `libstdc++.so.6` .... I.e. 'libstdc++.so.6' must be "gcc version 5.x". Please edit your question to include OS name and version.

Comment: @KnudLarsen i have added the os details.

Comment: `tar xvf libstdc++6_5.3.0_amd64.tar.gz` anywhere, and include it in "lib path" : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[dir. with libstdc++.so.6.0.21]:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && gn gen .... .. ..` . Link https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgslmjagwo47nyi/libstdc%2B%2B6_5.3.0_amd64.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: FAILED: pyproto/cc/proto/point3f_pb2.py gen/cc/proto/point3f.pb.cc gen/cc/proto/point3f.pb.h 
python ../../tools/protoc_wrapper/protoc_wrapper.py --include cc/proto/cc_proto_export.h --protobuf gen/cc/proto/point3f.pb.h --proto-in-dir ../../cc/proto --proto-in-file point3f.proto --use-system-protobuf=0 -- ./protoc --cpp_out dllexport_decl=CC_PROTO_EXPORT:gen/cc/proto --python_out pyproto/cc/proto
./protoc: relocation error: ./protoc: symbol _ZTTNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference

Comment: @KnudLarsen no luck :-( i tired as per your suggestion.i have pasted the error above.thanks

Comment: Ysurf : The required command is missing. ... An error output without the command causing the error is  not very useful .

Comment: @KnudLarsen here is command i used
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pp:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && gn gen out-target/Desktop --args='is_debug=false symbol_level=0  proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" use_cfi_diag=true enable_nacl=false treat_warnings_as_errors = true'

 ninja -C out-target/Desktop phoenix

Comment: »» `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pp:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && gn ..` «« : Which means that `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21` must be present in `/home/pp/` !

Comment: @KnudLarsen yes it is present i had untar at /homr/pp.